# Form n/2 with n amount of ANY number

Tags: formation-of-numbers

For every $n, m \in \mathbb{N}; n,m > 1$, construct a method to produce $\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor$ using *n m*s.

You can use:
$$x+y$$
$$x-y$$
$$x*y$$
$$\frac{x}{y}$$
$$x^y$$
$$x\bmod y$$
$$\sqrt[k]{x} : k \in \mathbb{N}$$
$$x!$$

I can't think of anything else now off the top of my head, but you get the general gist.

**NO TRIG FUNCTIONS.**

Yes, I mean to write something which tells you how to write an equation to form n/2 with n m's, it doesn't matter what n is or m is, it MUST work!

Comment: When you say that it doesn't matter what n or m is, do you mean it must work *for all* m and n, or do you mean that the answerer is free to choose any convenient m and n? (E.g. I choose n=2 and any non-zero m, and we can get n/2 = m/m = 1.)

Comment: It's easy for even $n$. just do $m/m + m/m + ...$ until you have $n m$s. not sure about odd $n$. $n = 1$ probably is impossible

Comment: @Lawrence Must work for all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the new rules, my m/m [idea](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/28138/form-n-2-with-n-amount-of-any-number/28140#comment83409_28138) and [Ivo Beckers' continuation](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/28139/9422):

For even $n$: $\frac{n}{2} = \frac{m}{m} + \frac{m}{m} + ...$.

For odd $n$: change the first term to $\frac{\sqrt{m}\sqrt{m}}{m}$.

Comment: @IvoBeckers probably the same reason I didn't think of extending the m/m idea :) .

Answer (score 3):

This is easy

For even $n$ do $\frac m m + \frac m m + ...$ until you have $n m$s.

**EDIT odd n is still incorrect, will fix it when i know a solution**
For odd $n$ do $\frac {m+m} m + \frac m m + \frac m m + \frac m m ...$

Comment: +1, but this doesn't form 4 with 5 ms (see the OP's edited example). Probably [a typo in the question](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/28138/form-n-2-with-n-amount-of-any-number?noredirect=1#comment83414_28138).

Comment: @Lawrence yeah you're right. It's a bit unclear what the OP is asking I guess.

Comment: Yeah, it should form 2 with 5ms.